Prevent expo notification alerts from being displayed
I am using a notification to trigger a refresh of data from an API.  Notifications are working but I do not want any alerts to be generated.  I've set the setNotificationHandler to null, and tried all options to false. But alerts are still showing while the app is in the foreground, background, killed, and phone off.  How can I prevent all alerts?
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";

// for notifications, don't show popups
Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
    handleNotification: async () => ({
        shouldShowAlert: false,
        shouldPlaySound: false,
        shouldSetBadge: false,
    }),
});

export default function App() {
...
}

